# How to reload UITableView when empty?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` works fine when adding a new row or deleting one.  When deleting all rows and wanting to see an empty table, `reloadData` has no affect.  All of the phantom rows are still there until the app is relunched.  I'm doing this on the `RootViewController`, which is a `UITableViewController`.  Is there another way to refresh the table in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths 
              withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

...on the UITableView when you delete some rows so you also get the animation when deleting

Otherwise a

```
[tableView setNeedsDisplay];
```

...might help

Comment: setNeedsDisplay never had any affect.  I'm deleting from the database and not one row at a time.  Not sure how deleteRowsAtIndexPaths can be used in that case.  I just need to refresh the table.

Comment: Figured it out.  Wasn't clearing out the source array after deleting from DB.